# Efficient way to convert second to minute and seconds in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql

Suppose I have 90 seconds. If I want to display the result in terms of minutes and second, I do it by using

```
select Time= '0' + CAST( 90/60 as varchar(2)) + ':' +  CAST( 90%60 as varchar(2))
```

The output is

> Time
>    01:30

I have appended 0(zero) because if you do a `select getdate()` the output will be

> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:ms

What is the standard way and recommended practice to do such a conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With hours:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,90,0),108)
00:01:30
```

Ignoring hours:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,90,0),108),5)
01:30
```

Comment: That's great.. but it is also showing the hour field. I need only mm:ss. Should I use a right to that e.g. SELECT right(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,90,0),108),5). Or any standard way is there

Comment: That's not working with seconds equal or more then these in one day: SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,86400,0),108)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(10), dateadd(second, 15794, 0), 108)
```

Comment: Down vote: because it does not answer the question. He wants minutes and seconds. You gave hours, minutes, and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first things I do on a fresh SQL database is add a `Timespan` function similar to this one (although I tend to include days and milliseconds as well):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TimeSpan
(
    @Hours int,
    @Minutes int,
    @Seconds int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(SS, @Hours * 3600 + @Minutes * 60 + @Seconds, 0)
END
```

Then you can format this however you want:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(8), dbo.TimeSpan(0, 0, 90), 108), 4, 5)
```

It might look more complicated at first, but the ability to reuse the `TimeSpan` function comes in very handy over time.  For me it feels like a hack to always be writing `DATEADD` calls against `0` or `'1753-01-01'`.

Comment: This solution only works with small numbers. For example, if you have 82816 seconds than SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(8), dbo.TimeSpan(0, 0, 82816), 108), 4, 5) returns only 16 seconds!