# SQL - Seconds to Day, Hour, Minute, Second

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient way to convert second to minute and seconds in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316288/efficient-way-to-convert-second-to-minute-and-seconds-in-sql-server-2005)

I have a query which needs to return the second in Day, Hour, Minute, Second format.

The below code works fine when its less than a day, but does not work, when the value in second is greater than a day

```
PRINT Convert(VarChar, DateAdd(S, 86400, 0), 108)
```

86400 is exactly a day and it returns 00:00:00

Can someone modify it and show me the result something like this

```
1:00:00:00.
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `DateAdd` at all? You need simple integer division and modulo operations. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2316288/62576), which you've pretty much duplicated.

Comment: Of course, not all days are 24 hours long, so that's why there's not a standard way of performing this conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
declare @days int, 
        @dt1 smalldatetime = '2012-03-25 03:24:16', 
        @dt2 smalldatetime = getdate()

set @days = datediff (s, @dt1, @dt2)


SELECT convert(char(10), @days / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':'
+ convert(char(10), dateadd(s, @days, convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108)

Result -- 170:20:40:00
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7b0d/37)

Comment: great solution for my project, but what do you store this result as in a SQL DB?

Comment: @htm11h You store the start & end date-times, or the Start time and duration (in this case seconds, as an int or bigint). The result is effectively a string only for display and formating purposes, it's not something you need to store in a database. In some databases there are real timespan datatypes but it's not vital.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
declare @seconds int=87500;

select cast(@seconds/86400 as varchar(50))+':'+
  Convert(VarChar, DateAdd(S, @seconds, 0), 108)
```

**Result**:

```
1:00:18:20
```