# TSQL Query returns values for each hour for the past 24 hours

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a query that I don't really know how to begin with. I'm hoping someone can help me out with it. I will start by explaining the table

I have a device table with four columns: Device_Id, Device_Status, Begin_dt, End_dt
there are 6 different statuses where 3 (for simplicity lets say status 1, 4 and 5) mean the device is 'online'

an example of this table could be

```
Id | Status| Begin                   |  End
001|     1 | 2012-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2012-09-01 01:00:00.000
001|     2 | 2012-09-01 01:00:00.000 | 2012-09-01 01:35:00.000
001|     1 | 2012-09-01 01:35:00.000 | 2012-09-01 02:05:00.000
003|     1 | 2012-09-01 05:00:00.000 | 2012-09-01 07:02:00.000
004|     1 | 2012-09-01 01:00:00.000 | 2012-09-01 01:35:00.000
003|     2 | 2012-09-01 07:02:00.000 | NULL
```

My query needs to return the Sum of the TIME all the devices have a status that indicates 'online' for each hour in a 24 hour period.

so my return should look like

```
Hour| Online_Time
0   | 5:30:12.11
1   | 3:30:12.11
2   | 4:30:12.11
3   | 5:30:12.11
4   | 6:30:12.11
5   | 4:00:00.00
6   | 1:30:12.11
7   | 3:30:12.11
8   | 4:30:12.11
etc |
```

So for each hour of the day I can have more than 1 hour of online time (obviously) because for example if I have 5 devices all online for the whole hour I would have 5 hours of online time for that hour.

This is kind of complex and I hope I did a good job of explaining it, anyone that can help or give a suggestion is greatly appreciated.

-J

---

```
with const as (
    select dateadd(hour, 1, cast(cast(getdate() -1 as date) as datetime)) as midnnight
    ),
allhours as (
    select 0 as hour, midnight as timestart, dateadd(hour, 1, timestart) as timeend from const union all
    select 1 as hour, dateadd(hour, 1, midnight), dateadd(hour, 2, midnight) from const union all
    select 2 as hour, dateadd(hour, 2, midnight), dateadd(hour, 3, midnight) from const union all
    select 3 as hour, dateadd(hour, 3, midnight), dateadd(hour, 4, midnight) from const union all
    select 4 as hour, dateadd(hour, 4, midnight), dateadd(hour, 5, midnight) from const union all
    select 5 as hour, dateadd(hour, 5, midnight), dateadd(hour, 6, midnight) from const union all
    select 6 as hour, dateadd(hour, 6, midnight), dateadd(hour, 7, midnight) from const union all
    select 7 as hour, dateadd(hour, 7, midnight), dateadd(hour, 8, midnight) from const union all
    select 8 as hour, dateadd(hour, 8, midnight), dateadd(hour, 9, midnight) from const union all
    select 9 as hour, dateadd(hour, 9, midnight), dateadd(hour, 10, midnight) from const union all
    select 10 as hour, dateadd(hour, 10, midnight), dateadd(hour, 11, midnight) from const union all
    select 11 as hour, dateadd(hour, 11, midnight), dateadd(hour, 12, midnight) from const union all
    select 12 as hour, dateadd(hour, 12, midnight), dateadd(hour, 13, midnight) from const union all
    select 13 as hour, dateadd(hour, 13, midnight), dateadd(hour, 14, midnight) from const union all
    select 14 as hour, dateadd(hour, 14, midnight), dateadd(hour, 15, midnight) from const union all
    select 15 as hour, dateadd(hour, 15, midnight), dateadd(hour, 16, midnight) from const union all
    select 16 as hour, dateadd(hour, 16, midnight), dateadd(hour, 17, midnight) from const union all
    select 17 as hour, dateadd(hour, 17, midnight), dateadd(hour, 18, midnight) from const union all
    select 18 as hour, dateadd(hour, 18, midnight), dateadd(hour, 19, midnight) from const union all
    select 19 as hour, dateadd(hour, 19, midnight), dateadd(hour, 20, midnight) from const union all
    select 20 as hour, dateadd(hour, 20, midnight), dateadd(hour, 21, midnight) from const union all
    select 21 as hour, dateadd(hour, 21, midnight), dateadd(hour, 22, midnight) from const union all
    select 22 as hour, dateadd(hour, 22, midnight), dateadd(hour, 23, midnight) from const union all
    select 23 as hour, dateadd(hour, 23, midnight), dateadd(hour, 24, midnight) from const union all
   ) 
select ah.hour,
   sum(datediff(ms, (case when ah.timestart >= dt.Begin_Dt then timestart else dt.Begin_Dt end),
                    (case when ah.timeend <= dt.End_Dt then ah.timeend else dt.End_Dt end))) as totalms,
   cast(dateadd(ms, sum(datediff(ms, (case when ah.timestart >= dt.Begin_Dt then timestart else dt.Begin_Dt end),
                                 (case when ah.timeend <= dt.End_Dt then ah.timeend else dt.End_Dt end))),0) as time
                                 ) as totalTime
from allhours as ah left outer join
     dataTable as dt
     on ah.timestart< coalesce(dt.End_dt, getdate()) and
        ah.timeend >= dt.Begin_Dt
group by ah.hour
order by ah.hour
```

---

This is what I have right now, I'm getting an error on the ')'

```
select 23 as hour, dateadd(hour, 23, midnight), dateadd(hour, 24, midnight) from const union all
   )  <----- Incorrect syntax near ')'. Expecting SELECT, or '('.
select ah.hour,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that the time span needs to be broken up in hours.  So, you need to start with all hours in the day.  Then you calculate the overlap, sum up the differences (below in milliseconds) and convert everything back to a time for the output.

```
with const as (
        select dateadd(hour, 1, cast(cast(getdate() -1 as date) as datetime)) as midnight            
    ),
    allhours as (
        select 0 as hour, midnight as timestart, dateadd(hour, 1, midnight) as timeend from const union all
        select 1 as hour, dateadd(hour, 1, midnight), dateadd(hour, 2, midnight) from const union all
        select 2 as hour, dateadd(hour, 2, midnight), dateadd(hour, 3, midnight)  from const union all
        . . .
        select 23 as hour, dateadd(hour, 23, midnight), dateadd(hour, 24, midnight) from const
    )
select ah.hour,
       sum(datediff(ms, (case when ah.timestart >= dt.begin then timestart else dt.begin end),
                        (case when ah.timeend <= dt.end then ah.timeend else dt.end end)
                   ) 
           ) as totalms,
       cast(dateadd(ms, sum(datediff(ms, (case when ah.timestart >= dt.begin then timestart else dt.begin end),
                                     (case when ah.timeend <= dt.end then ah.timeend else dt.end end)
                                    )
                           ),
                     0) as time
           ) as totalTime
from allhours ah left outer join
     DeviceTable dt
     on ah.timestart< coalesce(dt.end, getdate()) and
        ah.timeend >= dt.begin
group by ah.hour
order by ah.hour
```

Also, to make this work, you need to wrap "begin" and "end" in double quotes or square brackets.  These are reserved words in T-SQL.  And you need to replace the ". . ." with additional lines for hours from 3 to 22.

Comment: Thank you for the response Gordon! However, I'm having a little trouble syntactically. Most of my experience is in vb.net and I have the basic sql/tsql knowledge. I actually was just introduced to the idea of CTE's today. I am doing some reading on the topic and it seems like I need to specify  column names in my CTE. So I'm a little confused on

Comment: with const as (
        select dateadd(hour, 1, cast(cast(getdate() -1 as date) as datetime)) as midnnight,),....                                                        Shouldn't it be something like..                                                                  with const (COLUMN NAME) as (
        select dateadd(hour, 1, cast(cast(getdate() -1 as date) as datetime)) as midnnight,

    ),

Any elaboration would be most helpful

Comment: @BrandonJ . . . I fixed the syntax problems.  You will need to change the names of begin and end, or wrap them in square brackets, for the query to actually work.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon, and yes I did make the changes to begin and end, but I'm still running into one syntax problem [sorry I'm new to this :( ]

Comment: ) Select ah.hour, ------- The syntax error is on the right parenthesis and it is saying Incorrect syntax near ')', Expecting SELECT, or '('. - which is confusing because the next line is a select statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started.

```
select  SUM(datediff(second, Begin_dt, End_dt)) as seconds_online
        ,DATEPART(hour, Begin_dt) as [hour]
from table
where device_status in (1,4,5)
group by DATEPART(hour, Begin_dt)
```

To format the result you may want to follow this question:

[SQL - Seconds to Day, Hour, Minute, Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379466/sql-seconds-to-day-hour-minute-second)

Comment: Thanks Johan, I will start with that. I'd up-vote your post, but I made an account just for this post and don't have the required reputation yet :/