# Syntax for TSQL Query and CTE query

Tags: t-sql, syntax, common-table-expression

I'm going to post my query at the end of this post here, but just exposition is required first. Please ignore the column names and table names but I have syntax errors in two spots. When I put this query with my CTE it tells me I have to first 'terminate the previous statement with a ;' Then I go onto alias a column name in the CTE and then it says 'The multi-part identifier "E.ActiveAGVs" could not be bound.'

I hope that I am explaining my problem well enough. If anyone can see what I'm trying to do and let me know if it will work or correct my syntax errors, I would really appreciate it.

```
Select A.move_hour as 'Hour', 
       isnull(B.move_count,0) as 'Current_Count', 
       isnull(C.move_count,0) as '1_Day_Previous', 
       isnull(D.move_count,0) as '2_Day_Previous',
       ISNULL (E.ActiveAGVs,0) as 'Active AGV''s'
           --^ Error right here
from
   (select distinct(DATEPART(HH, Move_History.Move_Dt)) as move_hour 
   from Move_History 
   where Plant_Id = 1 and Building_Id = 1) as A
left outer join
   (select datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt) as move_hour, 
           Move_History.Move_Cnt as move_count 
   from Move_History 
Group by datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt), Move_Cnt) as B on A.move_hour = B.move_hour
left outer join
(select datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt) as move_hour, Move_History.Move_Cnt as       move_count 
from Move_History 
Group by datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt), Move_Cnt) as C on A.move_hour = C.move_hour
left outer join
(select datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt) as move_hour, Move_History.Move_Cnt as move_count 
from Move_History 
Group by datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt), Move_Cnt) as D on A.move_hour = D.move_hour;
with const as (
    select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) as midnight
    ),
allhours as (
    select 0 as m_hour, midnight as timestart, dateadd(hour, 1, midnight) as timeend from const union all
   ...
    select 23 as m_hour, dateadd(hour, 23, midnight) as timestart, dateadd(hour, 24, midnight) as timeend from const
   ) 
(select ah.m_hour,
   (sum(datediff(SECOND, timestart), ah.timeend else dt.End_Dt end)) 
   / 18000.0) * 5 as ActiveAGVs              
from allhours as ah
 left outer join AGV_Report as dt
 on ah.timestart< coalesce(dt.End_dt, getdate()) and
    ah.timeend >= dt.Begin_Dt
Group by datepart(SECOND,ah.hour), ah.timestart) as E on A.move_hour = E.move_hour
                                   --^ 'Incorrect syntax near "as"'
 where A.move_hour is not null
order by ah.m_hour asc
```

Comment: This SQL is nearly impossible to read.  Can you format it to make it more readable?  I tried, but it was sucking out my will to live.

Comment: I deleted some stuff That I don't think is necessary for what I am asking.

Comment: Alias `E` is the result of the query in which you refer to a column in `E`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All CTEs that you need to define for a statement, must go at the beginning of the statement. Even though the CTEs are going to be used only in one of the subqueries, the syntax still requires them to be placed at the beginning of the entire statement, *not* at the beginning of the particular subquery where they are actually referenced.

Therefore, your statement should probably look something like this:

```
;  -- required if there are statements preceding
with const as (
    select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) as midnight
    ),
allhours as (
    select
       0 as m_hour,
       midnight as timestart,
       dateadd(hour, 1, midnight) as timeend
    from const
    union all
   ...
    select
       23 as m_hour,
       dateadd(hour, 23, midnight) as timestart,
       dateadd(hour, 24, midnight) as timeend
    from const
   )
Select A.move_hour as 'Hour', 
       isnull(B.move_count,0) as 'Current_Count', 
       isnull(C.move_count,0) as '1_Day_Previous', 
       isnull(D.move_count,0) as '2_Day_Previous',
       ISNULL (E.ActiveAGVs,0) as 'Active AGV''s'
from
   (
      select distinct
         DATEPART(HH, Move_History.Move_Dt) as move_hour 
      from Move_History 
      where Plant_Id = 1 and Building_Id = 1
   ) as A
left outer join
   (
      select
         datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt) as move_hour, 
         Move_History.Move_Cnt as move_count 
      from Move_History 
      Group by datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt), Move_Cnt
   ) as B on A.move_hour = B.move_hour
left outer join
   (
      select
         datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt) as move_hour,
         Move_History.Move_Cnt as move_count 
      from Move_History 
      Group by datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt), Move_Cnt
   ) as C on A.move_hour = C.move_hour
left outer join
   (
      select
         datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt) as move_hour,
         Move_History.Move_Cnt as move_count 
      from Move_History 
      Group by datepart(HH,Move_History.Move_Dt), Move_Cnt
   ) as D on A.move_hour = D.move_hour
left outer join  -- assuming...
   (
      select
         ah.m_hour,
         (sum(datediff(SECOND, timestart), ah.timeend else dt.End_Dt end))
         / 18000.0) * 5 as ActiveAGVs              
      from allhours as ah
      left outer join AGV_Report as dt
         on ah.timestart < coalesce(dt.End_dt, getdate())
        and ah.timeend >= dt.Begin_Dt
      Group by datepart(SECOND,ah.hour), ah.timestart
   ) as E on A.move_hour = E.move_hour
where A.move_hour is not null
order by ah.m_hour asc
```

Comment: @BrandonJ, Andriy M's answer fixes the CTE syntax, but you will now see an error because `datediff` requires three parameters.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: Good point. Perhaps, `ah.timeend` was supposed to be the third argument, but Brandon should probably clarify that. Also I can see that there's `else` without `case` in the `E` subselect, but, again, it's unclear what the actual case expression should look like.

Comment: Absolutely. I directed the comment to Brandon, because I would not expect a Stack Overflow answer to completely clean up syntax on such a large statement. However a heads up on the next problem that will need his attention seemed like a nice thing to do.

Comment: Thank both ofyou, yeah the date diff and the else are both working fine in my actual query. It was just a very jumbled query so I was removing a bunch of the (what i thought was) extra stuff, so people could try and help me easier. And your solution works great! the only thing is at the very last group by, I'm doing something wrong. Using intellisence i can do 'as E on A.move_hour = E.m_hour' but I then get the error 'Column 'allhours.m_hour' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' but I'm using ah.m_hour in my datepart

Comment: never mind guys! 'Group by ah.m_hour) as E on A.move_hour = E.m_hour' worked fine. Thanks so much again!!!

Answer (score 0):

A common table expression (CTE) must be separated from any prior statement by a semicolon (;).  If no statements precede the `with` then there is no need for a semicolon.

You can have multiple CTEs within a single `with`.  An example follows:

```
with
  -- Counting numbers.
  Numbers as (
    select 1 as Number
    union all
    select Numbers.Number + 1
      from Numbers
      where Number < 10 ),
  -- Squares of counting numbers.
  Squares as (
    select Number, Number * Number as Square
      from Numbers )
  -- Result.
  select Number, Square
    from Squares
```

Like the rest of the people trying to help, I have no idea of what your SQL is trying to do.

Comment: I'm really only trying to do one recursive CTE. I'm kind of new to CTE's so I asked a question on this forum earlier, and received help by someone. The CTE itself works fine and returns what I want it to, but when I try to use it with the main query it doesn't like that. check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387873/tsql-query-returns-values-for-each-hour-for-the-past-24-hours

Comment: @BrandonJ, the CTE here and at prior question is not recursive. A recursive CTE refers to itself, `with X as (select . . . union all seleect . . . from X . . .)`