# Calculate number of days between 2 dates, then sum and group by month

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm querying a view that gives me data about multiple hospital patient episodes. It includes two columns that give me the start date of an episode, and an end date.

What I'm attempting to do (bed stay calculations, for anyone NHS) is calculate how many days fall between the 2 dates (easy), but then group the day count by the month it falls in.

e.g. if Startdate = 17th November 2016, and Enddate = 3rd Jan 2017, I'm after an output along the lines of:

```
Year | Month | No. Bed Days |
-----------------------------
2016 |  11   |     13       |
2016 |  12   |     31       |
2017 |  1    |      3       |
```

I've got some code that kind of works along the lines I'm after, based on inputting date parameters:

```
declare @dtFrom date 
declare @dtTo date

select @dtFrom = '2016-11-17'
      ,@dtTo   = '2017-01-03'


select year(dt) [Year], month(dt) [Month],  count(*) 'No. Bed Days'
from (select top(datediff(d, @dtFrom, @dtTo)) dateadd(d,  row_number() over (order by (select null)), @dtFrom) dt
      from sys.columns) q
group by year(dt), month(dt)
order by [Year], [Month]
```

However, because the data contains hundreds of episodes and I want to calculate and sum the bed days for all of these into the single table, rather than supplying date parameters, I want to point the code to the view `Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes` and use the following variables to supply the parameters from the data: `Episode_Start_Date` `Episode_End_Date`.

I've tried modifying the code to declare the variable names as the parameters, and tried modifying the code to point to the view (as below), but I'm just getting syntax errors.

Please can anyone advise on how to correctly formulate the syntax?

```
select year(dt) [Year], month(dt) [Month],  count(*) 'No. Bed Days'
from Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes
where
(select top(datediff(d, Episode_Start_Date, Episode_End_Date)) dateadd(d,  row_number() over (order by (select null)), Episode_Start_Date) dt
      from sys.columns) q
group by year(dt), month(dt)
order by [Year], [Month]
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a Date Dimension you could join against? That would make this a lot simpler.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389351/92546) answer deals with times and hours rather than dates and months, but the basics are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @Kannan_Kandasamy, the solution was obtained by combining a cross apply approach to the original query, as below:

```
select year(dt) [Year], month(dt) [Month],  count(*) 'No. Bed Days'
from Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes
cross apply
(
select top(datediff(day, Episode_Start_Date, Episode_End_Date)) dateadd(d,  row_number() over (order by (select null)), Episode_Start_Date) dt
      from sys.columns) q
group by year(dt), month(dt)
order by [Year], [Month]
```

Answer (score 3):

I you you want to generate days between tow dates, Please check approach below

```
declare @dtFrom date    = '2016-11-17'
declare @dtTo date      = '2017-01-03'

select  year(RowN)  as [Year],
        Month(RowN) as [Month],
        count(*)    as [No of Bed Days] from (
    select top(datediff(day, @dtfrom, @dtto)+1) RowN = dateadd(day, ( row_number() over(order by (select null)) - 1), @dtFrom) 
    from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
) a
group by year(a.RowN), Month(a.RowN)
```

Output:

```
+------+-------+----------------+
| Year | Month | No of Bed Days |
+------+-------+----------------+
| 2017 |     1 |              3 |
| 2016 |    11 |             14 |
| 2016 |    12 |             31 |
+------+-------+----------------+
```

I think my query considers first day as well and if you do not require that you can change accordingly. Also you can do cross apply to your table if you have start and end dates in different table. But Ideal performance scenario is to have date dimension like generated table and do join to that is the faster approach.

I changed your query as below using cross-apply

```
select year(dt) [Year], month(dt) [Month],  count(*) 'No. Bed Days'
from Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes
cross apply
(
    select top(datediff(day, fromdatefromyourtable, todatefromyourtable)+1) dt = dateadd(day, ( row_number() over(order by (select null)) - 1), fromdatefromyourtable) from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
) q
group by year(dt), month(dt)
order by [Year], [Month]
```

You need to replace fromdatefromyourtable - to fromdate column of your table and todatefromyourtable - to todate column from your table.

Comment: Many thanks @Kannan - this has helped me to get what I need. As you suggested, the query includes the first day (which I need to discount), so I used a combination of the initial query I was using plus your cross apply approach, and this is giving me the results I require. I'll post this separately as an answer to the question. Greatly appreciate your time. Regards, Jon

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear when you say this part: 'However, because the data contains hundreds of episodes and I want to calculate and sum the bed days for all of these into the single table, rather than supplying date parameters, I want to point the code to the view Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes and use the following variables to supply the parameters from the data: Episode_Start_Date Episode_End_Date.'  what you mean.  We cannot see your table structures unless you present them.  So does it self contain everything you need and you just want to present on top of that?  I can give a self extracting example of how I would do this problem.  I tend to not favor doing the group by (metric1), (metric2), etc when it is a date.  I like to do the sql syntax trick of:

```
DateAdd((precision), DateDiff(Precision), 0, (yourDateField), 0)
```

This essentially does all the grouping in one shot for you and is in a DateTime format already.  I would do the groupings like so:

```
--Add Some test data
DECLARE @Dates TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY, Dt DATETIME)
DECLARE 
  @StartD DATE = '2016-8-1'
, @EndD DATE = '2017-5-1'
;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

WHILE @StartD <= @EndD
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Dates (Dt)
    VALUES (@StartD)

    SELECT @StartD = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartD)
END


DECLARE
  @Start DateTime = '2016-8-21'
, @End DateTime = '2017-4-10'
;

SELECT
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Dt), 0)
, COUNT(*) AS DayCount
From @Dates
WHERE Dt BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Dt), 0)

SELECT 
  @Start = '2016-10-25'
, @End = '2017-4-2'
;

SELECT
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Dt), 0)
, COUNT(*) AS DayCount
From @Dates
WHERE Dt BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Dt), 0)

--If I simply want to have another table do the join that's not hard
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (St DATETIME, Ed DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('2016-12-8', '2017-2-7')

SELECT
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Dt), 0)
, COUNT(*) AS DayCount
From dbo.SomeData
WHERE Dt BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(St) FROM @Temp) AND (SELECT MAX(Ed) FROM @Temp)
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Dt), 0)
```