# T-SQL formatting calculated column as time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Could use guru help on this one. Trying to calculate the time between two datetime values and show as time in a T-SQL query...

```
SELECT arrivalDate - departDate AS timeToComplete
```

This should always be less than 24 hours. But who knows what the user may actually input?

I have been trying something like this with no resutls.

```
SELECT  
   CAST(time(7), 
   CONVERT(datetime, arrivalDate - departDate) AS timeToComplete) AS newTime,
```

Instead of showing results as `1:23:41` as an example, is there a way to show results like:

```
0D, 1H, 23M, 33S.
```

Thanks for any guidance on this.

Comment: you can look also at my updated example which achieve your requirement in the select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be different :)
Try to use this approach:

declare @date1 datetime;
declare @date2 datetime;

```
set @date1 = '2012-05-01 12:00:000'
set @date2 = '2012-05-01 18:00:000'


    SELECT 
    STUFF(
        STUFF(
            STUFF(
                RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(S, @date1, @date2), '20000101')), 120), 11), 
                3, 1, 'D, '), 
            8, 1, 'H, '), 
        13, 1, 'M, ') + ' S';
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to convey here. First there are a number of missing parenthesis, and I would like to use this in a SELECT statement.

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake when copied the query, I've successfully run this query. Unfortunately sqlfiddle isnt accesible for me now and I cant share query with you.

Comment: @roman why was sqlfiddle not accessible for you? Anything wrong with the site?

Comment: Yes, I had strange error :). Now everything works fine. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bb21/4

Comment: @Roman I liked your solution better, and I plan to change my code over to your solution when I have a moment. Gave you the credit for the solution. Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You could get the total difference in seconds and then keep taking the largest part out of that. I.e., start with Days, then hours, minutes and seconds.

```
DECLARE @arrivalDate DATETIME = '2013-01-19 23:59:59'
DECLARE @departDate DATETIME = '2013-01-25 11:52:30'

DECLARE @SecondsDifference INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @arrivalDate, @departDate)

DECLARE @DayDifference INT = @SecondsDifference / 86400
DECLARE @HourDifference INT = (@SecondsDifference - (@DayDifference * 86400)) / 3600
DECLARE @MinDifference INT = (@SecondsDifference - (@DayDifference * 86400) - (@HourDifference * 3600)) / 60
DECLARE @SecDifference INT = (@SecondsDifference - (@DayDifference * 86400) - (@HourDifference * 3600) - (@MinDifference * 60))
```

I've done it here using variables for clarity, but you could work this into a single query. DATEDIFF wont work for the smaller chunks of the difference until you remove the larger ones because you'd get the totals. For example:

```
DATEDIFF(HOUR, @arrivalDate, @departDate)
```

would return the total number of hours, not the hours less the whole days.

Comment: Wow, this could be tough to code, but I think its probably going to handle my issue best. Trying to do this in a SQL Datasource control. Thanks

Comment: It might be suitable to make it into a function that returns either the fully formatted string (eg. "0D, 12H, 30M, 25S"), or returns a dataset with Integer Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds columns. That way you could call it in-line in your datasource.

Comment: I posted an update, with a link to a solution that seems to work quite well. thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a great solution at this link,
[SQL - Seconds to Day, Hour, Minute, Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379466/sql-seconds-to-day-hour-minute-second)
thanks for the help though folks, it got me further into this issue and searching for the right info.