# Converting Excel in to SQL

Tags: sql, excel

Hi All Below are the results of my query with the added column to find out the time between 2 events. I have also suppled the code I have so far along with my mistake!

```
SELECT
PAN.[FULL PARCEL ID], 
PAN.[12 DIGIT PARCEL ID], 
PAN.[NO OF PARCELS], 
PAN.[SERVICE ID], 
PAN.[PAN PROCESS DATE TIME],
PAN.[Late Time Measure DD:HH:MM], 
PAN.[1ST PHYSICAL SCAN], 
PAN.[HUB SCAN], 
PAN.[SORT LOCATION], 
PAN.[PAN STATUS], 
PAN.[PAN FUNCTION], 
RLZ.ReportGroup,
ORD.PicksetNo,
ORD.PicksetPrintTS,
TASK.TaskStart,
TASK.TaskEnd,
ORD.PicksetConfirmTS,
ORD.EarliestPickDate
FROM CHDS_Sandbox.dbo.PANTEST PAN
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.OMOrder ORD ON ORD.AddressBarcode = PAN.[FULL PARCEL ID]
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.RackListZone RLZ ON RLZ.Loc = ORD.ProductWhsLocation
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.TaskScan TASK ON TASK.Pickset = ORD.PicksetNo
```

I need to find out the time difference between When ORD.PicksetConfirmTS happend and when PAN.[1ST PHYSICAL SCAN] happened. I need thisa to also show negative times.

I have tried:

```
CONCAT(
       DATEDIFF(DAY, PAN.[PAN PROCESS DATE TIME], ORD.PicksetConfirmTS),'-',
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, PAN.[PAN PROCESS DATE TIME], ORD.PicksetConfirmTS),':',
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PAN.[PAN PROCESS DATE TIME], ORD.PicksetConfirmTS),':',
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, PAN.[PAN PROCESS DATE TIME], ORD.PicksetConfirmTS))
```

But I eneded up with -1--12-456-12345 on the negative ones.

The Excel was simple:

```
=IF(E2-N2<0,"-"&TEXT(ABS(E2-N2),"dd - hh:mm"),TEXT(ABS(E2-N2),"dd - hh:mm"))

FULL PARCEL ID  NO OF PARCELS   PAN PROCESS DATE TIME   Late Time Measure DD:HH:MM  1ST PHYSICAL SCAN   HUB SCAN    SORT LOCATION   PAN STATUS  ReportGroup PicksetNo   PicksetPrintTS  TaskStart   TaskEnd PicksetConfirmTS    EarliestPickDate
JJD2102210131951257 1   02/01/2018 21:40    00:00:11    02/01/2018 21:29    02/01/2018 21:29    Las Vasg    LATE    UGLY    181436  02/01/2018 15:13    (null)  (null)  02/01/2018 21:02    02/01/2018
JJD2102210131988232 1   07/01/2018 21:16    00:00:16    07/01/2018 21:00    07/01/2018 21:00    Italy   LATE    UGLY    183155  07/01/2018 16:22    (null)  (null)  07/01/2018 20:39    07/01/2018
JJD2102210131951259 1   02/01/2018 21:40    00:00:11    02/01/2018 21:29    02/01/2018 21:29    Las Vasg    LATE    UGLY    181436  02/01/2018 15:13    (null)  (null)  02/01/2018 21:02    02/01/2018
JJD2102210131951260 1   02/01/2018 21:40    00:00:17    02/01/2018 21:23    02/01/2018 21:23    Las Vasg    LATE    UGLY    181436  02/01/2018 15:13    (null)  (null)  02/01/2018 21:02    02/01/2018
JJD2102210131951261 1   02/01/2018 21:40    00:00:17    02/01/2018 21:23    02/01/2018 21:23    Las Vasg    LATE    UGLY    181436  02/01/2018 15:13    (null)  (null)  02/01/2018 21:02    02/01/2018
JJD2102210190421300 1   02/01/2018 21:39    00:00:51    02/01/2018 20:48    02/01/2018 20:48    Las Vasg    LATE    UGLY    181382  02/01/2018 12:47    (null)  (null)  02/01/2018 21:22    02/01/2018
JJD2102210190434368 1   07/01/2018 21:15    00:00:01    07/01/2018 21:14    07/01/2018 21:14    Italy   LATE    UGLY    183155  07/01/2018 16:22    (null)  (null)  07/01/2018 20:39    07/01/2018
JJD2102210190434367 1   07/01/2018 21:15    00:00:14    07/01/2018 21:01    07/01/2018 21:01    Italy   LATE    UGLY    183155  07/01/2018 16:22    (null)  (null)  07/01/2018 20:39    07/01/2018
JJD2102210190436947 1   09/01/2018 16:39    00:00:01    09/01/2018 16:38    09/01/2018 16:38    Italy   LATE    UGLY    183613  09/01/2018 06:22    (null)  (null)  09/01/2018 16:23    09/01/2018
```

Thank you for any help provided on this.

Comment: Can you supply a table with sample data? Calculating time differences in SQL is simple if you use the correct data types. Also please share the version of SQL server etc. you are using

Comment: SQL Server 2016 How can I upload the table?

Comment: 1. Create a dummy table with data. 2. Paste te code to create the table including the dummy values here. NEVER share production data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to convert second to minute and seconds in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316288/efficient-way-to-convert-second-to-minute-and-seconds-in-sql-server-2005) and its respective duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/12379507/1132334 - what you're currently doing is expressing the same datediff in different resolutions. what you need is dividing per each unit of time.

Comment: I have tried to do the table thing

Comment: @dlatikay Not rally as I am trying to find the differance and then convert it in to dd - hh:mm.

Comment: yes but then the missing link is just the `DATEDIFF(SECOND...)` as the input to the solution described in the other answers. I'll try to write it up unless someone else beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula of this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12380293/1132334,

we can write

```
SELECT
    case SIGN(DATEDIFF(SECOND, ORD.PicksetConfirmTS, PAN.[PAN PROCESS DATE TIME])) WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE '-' END+
    cast(ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, ORD.PicksetConfirmTS, PAN.[PAN PROCESS DATE TIME]))/86400 as varchar(50))+':'+
    convert(varchar,DATEADD(S,ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, ORD.PicksetConfirmTS, PAN.[PAN PROCESS DATE TIME])),0),108)
```

The fact that we need to include the computation of seconds twice is a bit unfortunate, but owed to query semantics.

The sign of the difference is preserved, sample output:

> -1:23:41:40

The problem with your original attempt was a logical one: the different `DATEDIFF` calls will have computed the same difference in all four cases, only in different units of time. Needed is a series of divisions. The `convert(..., 108)` function does the heavy lifting from seconds until hours, just for the days we need to do it on our own, the magic number 86400 is the amount of seconds in a day.

Comment: Thanks You. I made a small change: 


   `CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,ORD.PicksetConfirmTS, PAN.[1ST PHYSICAL SCAN])/86400 as varchar(50))+':'+
    CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(S,DATEDIFF(SECOND, ORD.PicksetConfirmTS, PAN.[1ST PHYSICAL SCAN]),0),108)`

Comment: But did find it was still making errors. Take 

 PAN.[1ST PHYSICAL SCAN =  02/01/2018 20:48:00  
PicksetConfirmTS  = 02/01/2018 21:22:00 
It is showing as 0:23:26:00 should this not read -0:00:34:00

Thank you for you help so far!

Comment: blimey, good catch. had to add an ABS so we get the absolute, unsigned distance in seconds for the hh:mm:ss part. see updated answer.

Comment: Aggg thisone is showing +38 but it should be -38

    `FULL PARCEL ID NO OF PARCELS PAN PROCESS DATE TIME 1ST PHYSICAL SCAN PicksetConfirmTS EarliestPickDate Taken Column1
JJD0002210132017283 1 12/01/2018 21:40:00 12/01/2018 20:46:00 12/01/2018 21:24:00 12/01/2018 -38 Min 0:00:38:00`

Comment: now it computes the sign first, then it does the rest with absolute distance. waiting for your next test case to destroy my formula.

Comment: thanks for your help @dlatikay going to try it when I get back in the office.

Comment: We went the long way around and used a function we created in the end:
    `BEGIN
   RETURN CASE 
    WHEN @vMinutes < 60 THEN CAST( @vMinutes AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Min'
    WHEN @vMinutes < 1440 THEN CAST(@vMinutes/60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Hr, ' + CAST(@vMinutes%60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Min'
    ELSE CAST(@vMinutes/(1440 ) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Days, ' + CAST((@vMinutes%1440 )/60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Hr, ' + CAST(((@vMinutes%1440 )%60) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Min'
    END`