# Transform number of seconds in (Date)Time format 'mm:ss' in Informix SQL

Tags: sql, datetime-format, informix

I'm requesting an Informix database with SQL. I have a column with numbers that represent a number of seconds. I want to transform this number to a time (mm:ss) format in my SQL statement. For example, the number '90' should be transformed into '01:30'. It's important that the new field shouldn't be a string field, but a (date)time field.

Comment: ANSI SQL: `cast( cast(column as interval second) as interval minute to second)`? (The inner cast converts the number 90 to the interval 90 seconds. The outer cast converts that to the interval 1:30 minute to second.

Comment: Maybe try something like ```SELECT CAST((CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,90,0),108)) AS DATETIME)```

And that's kinda a dupplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316288/efficient-way-to-convert-second-to-minute-and-seconds-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: I'm sure there is a 'less' complicate method than these two but, specific for Informix, you can use `SELECT (CURRENT - (CURRENT - 90 UNITS SECOND))::INTERVAL MINUTE TO SECOND FROM TABLE(SET{1})` to get an INTERVAL, or `SELECT ((CURRENT - (CURRENT - 90 UNITS SECOND))::INTERVAL MINUTE TO SECOND)::LVARCHAR::DATETIME MINUTE TO SECOND FROM TABLE(SET{1})` to get a DATETIME (both minute to second). If you have more than 3600 seconds you may need to use HOUR TO SECOND.

Comment: What type is the 'column of numbers'?  Is it INTEGER, or some other integer type, or is it a DECIMAL type?  What is the range of values in the column?  Are any negative?  What is the desired output if the value is 3600 or more (seconds in an hour)?  86400 or more (seconds in a day)?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct this as:

```
select floor(secs / 60) || ':' || lpad(mod(secs, 60), 2, '0')
```

Comment: That's great! Any suggestions to convert the result from string to a (date)time field?

Comment: @mattiedf . . . I don't think Informix has a `time` datatype.  In a database that does, you would simply use `cast(<expression> as time)`.

Comment: @mattiedf — You could use DATETIME MINUTE TO SECOND or DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND as the 'time' type, depending on what value should be printed when the input is 10000 seconds as opposed to 90 seconds.  But the question is also 'should this be an INTERVAL (elapsed amount of time) or a DATETIME (moment in time)?'  It isn't clear what you want to do next.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATETIME(0:0) MINUTE TO SECOND + colname UNITS SECOND
  FROM data_table
```

This would convert the row containing a numeric value 90 to the value `01:30` with type `DATETIME MINUTE TO SECOND`.  You can vary the type to deal with larger values:

```
SELECT DATETIME(0:0:0) HOUR TO SECOND + colname UNITS SECOND
  FROM data_table
```

This will process non-negative values from 0 to 86399 producing answers from `00:00:99` to `23:59:59` of type DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND.

You can add up to 5 fractional digits of seconds if desired.

If the input values can be negative or 86400 or larger, then you have to define what you want — you will get an error if the value is 3600 in the first example, or 86400 or larger in the second.